# Unity 4 Character Mesh Collider not aligned - character falls through. Image attached inc source unity asset link

Tags: character, unity-game-engine, mesh, rigid-bodies

Hello Peeps (first post yay).

I have just started to learn about unity and still going through various tutorials and learning the interface along with C#.

I am running Unity 4 and downloaded a free asset from the Unity store:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3174

The Problem. 
I created a Plane in Unity. 
Went to the Character and created colliders and imported it as a humanoid. 
Then added a rigid body = **The character fell through the plane**
I then added a Mesh collider and attached the mesh for the character to the collider. The mesh does NOT align correctly to the character = **the character fell through the plane.**
I then tried box and capsule colliders and they worked fine. **Attached these and the character would not fall through.**
I then tried a character controller = Character did not fall through.

I want to have an accurate mesh for this test character so when an enemy hits him, there is an actual hit.

I have tried several other free characters from the store and they all have the same problem. Can someone please tell me how I can fix this? It seems I just either doing something completely wrong, missing a step or just plain lost.

Link below to image of the issue taken:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using a mesh collider on a skinned, animated character is a wrong approach. Mesh colliders are generally used for environment geometry and rigid objects. This is all due to the amount of work it is needed for the Unity engine to accurately calculate the shape of the mesh collider, based on the provided mesh. More triangles means more work, and for the reasonably complex low poly character mesh of 10k to 30k triangles it is clear that the fps would most definitely drop to an unplayable level.

For our game we are using all primitive colliders, distributed on the adequate bone game objects. So, head bone has a sphere collider, spine has a box collider (for lungs), forearm has a capsule collider etc. That way,with a little bit of scripting, you can detect a hit and know exactly what part of body is damaged.

Answer (score 2):

If your collider doesn't exactly match your mesh, then it's likely that you have the mesh applied to the wrong part of the object.

Try applying the Mesh Collider to the mesh, instead of the complete object.

Comment: I tried that. I added the mesh collider to the actual character mesh object. It aligns but makes no difference. Character still falls through. It seems I am being forced into using the Capsule collider, which I want to avoid.

Comment: That shouldn't be needed. Can you upload a photo in which you expand the object 'baseMaleOM'? So I can see which objects are in it?

Comment: So when adding the mesh collider to an other part, your collider aligns correctly now? If so, try replacing your plane by something with more depth, like a cube. It might sound silly but objects with collision detection tend to go through slim objects often, especially with mesh colliders.

Comment: tried that as well. Set the cube to 100, 10, 100 to add some depth. Same issue. The more I look at the issue the more I think capsule collider is the only way to go. Eventually I want to run this on the iOS so having more than one collider is going to be taxing on the CPU

Comment: I think I am going to go down a different route. Been looking into ragdoll wizard. It creates rigid bodies based on the mesh/bones. I am going to use a ragdoll and create a prefab of this ragdoll (no animations, just normal character with rigid bodies applied via wizard). I'll then create a character standard prefab and build out my character this way. I'll be using C# to code through everything and ensure everything works as it should and I can then get on with building the various character scripts. So I am going for a character controller, custom character controller scripts, ragdoll

Comment: Well, like you said yourself, perhaps it's better to go for capsule collider since you are on an iOS platform. Still, I'd like to know what happens here. I mean it's always possible to find a workaround but when you figure out why something didn't work instead of working around it, you might learn something from it. I'd like to ask again, does the collider fit around the character correctly now when you've moved the mesh collider on a different part of the object? Or is it still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty complex character mesh, so using mesh collider probably isn't the best way to go. In many cases, character controller or capsule collider works fine; otherwise, you can just use compound collider and create a box or a sphere around various body parts of the character.

Answer (score 0):

This once happened to me. The mistake i made was, i applied the mesh collider after i did some rotation and scaling. So i added the mesh collider as soon as i imported the model. And then it should be alright when you scale/edit the model. Also check with right/left handed co-ordinate system with unity and 3D MAX/Maya.